# How can I group the number of values into columns based on month in sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data set like

```
Code Date 
123  21-Jan-2000 
234  23-Feb-1999 
123  19-Jan-2001
```

and I would like to query the table to display the data like this:

```
Code Total (All months) Jan Feb ... Dec 
123    2                 1   1
234    1                 0   1
```

I really have no idea how to start this. Any hints or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    Code,
    COUNT(Date) AS "Total (All months)",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 1  THEN 1 END) AS Jan,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 2  THEN 1 END) AS Feb,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 3  THEN 1 END) AS Mar,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 4  THEN 1 END) AS Apr,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 5  THEN 1 END) AS May,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 6  THEN 1 END) AS Jun,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 7  THEN 1 END) AS Jul,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 8  THEN 1 END) AS Aug,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 9  THEN 1 END) AS Sep,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 10 THEN 1 END) AS Oct,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 11 THEN 1 END) AS Nov,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) = 12 THEN 1 END) AS Dec
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Code
ORDER BY
    Code;
```

Note that the above explicit pivot syntax can often outperform the counterpart which uses the `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: is there a way to display the total as 0 if all months have 0 values cause it's currently showing 1 right now

Comment: @llamaro25 Try counting the `Date` column.  A zero total should only be possible if a given code has one or more records all of whose `Date` is `NULL`.  Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `PIVOT`. From the [official documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html):

```
select * from (
   select times_purchased, state_code
   from customers t
)
pivot 
(
   count(state_code)
   for state_code in ('NY','CT','NJ','FL','MO')
)
order by times_purchased
```

So in your case, the following query:

```
select * from (
    select code, datepart(month, date) as month
      from #data
) as data
pivot 
(
    count(code)
     for month in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
)
```